# Simulating a person for use with Turtlebot_simulator and turtlebot_follower

Tags: gazebo, simulation, turtlebot, turtlebot-simulator

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Running Ros Hydro and Gazebo 1.9

How would I go about creating a human model or even just something similar that would allow the follower package to work effectively.

I just need to have marginal control over the path the simulated human takes, something like, walk in a square over and over again.

Thanks.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/85571/simulating-a-person-for-use-with-turtlebot_simulator-and-turtlebot_follower/) by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on ROS Answers with karma: 103 on 2013-09-30

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It is rather easy to add static human 3D models from google sketchup, for instance see http://sketchup.google.com/3dwarehouse/details?mid=45a705cf8bbfbcc771a53b84547e90a&ct=mdsa&prevstart=0, following instructions in this [gazebo tutorial](http://gazebosim.org/user_guide/started__models__database.html). These models are quite realistic and face detectors work well with them. Nevertheless, how to animate them is an open question that we are interest in too.

---

Originally posted by [Jordi Pages](https://answers.ros.org/users/626/jordi-pages/) with karma: 245 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-10-01**:
This looks great, I don't necessarily need it animated. I would settle for just having move my sliding along the ground. I'm assuming this won't be too hard. If you have any pointers, let me know.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Well, turtlebot_follower "human" detection is very crude: it will follow anything in front of the robot big enough to generate a pointcloud of more than 4000 points...

---

Originally posted by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) with karma: 2284 on 2013-09-30

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-09-30**:
Well that's probably good enough for my purposes. Is simulating humanoids largly out of the question?

**Comment by [jorge](https://answers.ros.org/users/1986/jorge/) on 2013-09-30**:
I guess that adding new models to gazebo must be easy, once you a have the sdf file, though I never did by myself. Btw, do you plan to make a more sophisticated follower that really discriminate humans?

**Comment by [Alkaros](https://answers.ros.org/users/6169/alkaros/) on 2013-10-01**:
I'm currently working on using the turtlebot to track a human and have it decide (With POMDP) when it's appropriate to scan the targets face to make sure it's still following the correct person. It's just an initial idea, for starters the simple follower package should work well enough for following.